# Number of $n$-length sequences such that...

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Find the number of sequences of length n such that every number $i \in \{1, 2, · · · , n\}$ appears exactly
twice and two consecutive numbers are always different.

That's from a homework set, although isn't it incorrect? I mean if you make a sequence that contains all of this i numbers twice then wouldn't its' length be 2n? Besides from that i cannot solve it anyway.

Comment: Yes, you need length $2n$.  I assume that is what they intended.

Comment: Have you tried inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: @Useless well no, I don't really even know how to apply this principle here, combinatorics has been my weak spot so far, I desperately need help

Comment: This is http://oeis.org/A114938 which has a link to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.04177.pdf that derives one formula by inclusion/exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint  consider inclusion-exclusion.  The nodes of  the poset here
contain the sequences  where some subset $Q\subseteq [n]$  or more are
adjacent. With  $q=|Q|$ there  are ${n\choose q}$  such sets.  We then
have

$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q \frac{(2n-q)!}{1^q 2^{n-q}}
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q \frac{(2n-q)!}{2^{n-q}}.$$

This will produce

$$0, 2, 30, 864, 39480, 2631600, 241133760,
\\  29083420800, 4467125013120\ldots $$

which is [OEIS A114938](https://oeis.org/A114938).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are two possible interpretations for the problem:

1. The length of the sequence is $2n$, and $n$ was a typo.
2. The possible elements of the sequence are the numbers $\{1, \dots, n\}$ and if a number is contained in the sequence, it must be contained exactly twice. However, not every number must be part of the sequence. E.g. for $n = 4$ we get solution set:

   $\{1212, 1313, 1414, 2121, 2323, 2424, 3131, 3232, 3434, 4141, 4242, 4343\}$

   This would mean that there are no solutions for odd $n$.

Answer (score 0):

We treat this problem as a question about balls: Given a bag of balls of $n$ different colors where each color occurs exactly twice, how many possibilities are there to draw all the balls out of the bag, without drawing two times the same color in a row. Clearly the answer to this answer is the total number of drawings ($2n!$) minus the number of rows in which two balls occur one after the other.

The number of cases in which two balls occur one after the other can be found by gluing two balls that are the same to each other (Since they have to be drawn one after the other), which leaves $$(2n-1)!$$ possibilities. This has to be multiplied by 2 for there are in fact two possibilities for the balls we draw one after the other, and multiplied by $n$ because it could be any ball. This make the total here $$2n(2n-1)!$$ Which gives a total of possibilities with no consecutive balls of $(2n)!-(2n)! = 0$.

We now remember we are in fact doing inclusion-exclusion and have removed  all cases with two consecutive pairs now, and have to compensate for that, the same approach as before now yields
$$2^2\begin{pmatrix}2n\\2\end{pmatrix}(2n-2)!$$.
Continuing this approach gives up to $n$ pairs being drawn one after the other, provides the answer
$$\sum_{i=n}^{2n} (-2)^{2n-i}\begin{pmatrix}2n\\2n-i\end{pmatrix}i!$$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the suggestion in comments: we use inclusion-exclusion principle to calculate $A$, the Answer. Call $A_k$ the set of sequences in which the number $k$ appears two times consecutively. We don't want to count these sets, right? So we take them out. But if we just subtract them from the total number of sequences, we take out two times, for instance, the set of sequences in which both 1,2 appears consecutively (i.e. $A_1 \cap A_2$). That's why we apply inclusion exclusion, and we get:

$$A =\sum_r (-1)^r \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_r} |A_{i_1} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_r} |$$

Let's evaluate $|A_{i_1} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_r} |$. It is the cardinality of the set of sequences in which $r$ numbers are forced to stay together: they constitute a block of 2 bricks. The other bricks are free, but every number occur twice. Thus we have the permutations of $2(n-r)+r = 2n-r$ blocks, and we have to divide by $2^{n-r}$,the number of possible swaps among free bricks. Putting into the formula, and noticing that there are $\binom{n}{r} $ summands of "type r", we get

$$A = \sum_r (-1)^r \binom{n}{r} \frac{(2n-r)!} {2^{n-r}} $$

You can verify that the result is correct for $n=1,2,3$. For $n=3$,you can suppose that the first two numbers in the sequence are 1,2,and then multiply by 6 (why?).